# GeoExt2 download source code

Tags: geoext

I use GeoExt2 in my app through online path:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        GeoExt: "http://geoext.github.com/geoext2/src/GeoExt/"
        ,'Ext.ux': 'http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.0.7-commercial/examples/ux'

    }
});
```

I need to have maps and popups available offline (without internet), so I think I have to download GeoExt2 source and use it locally. Is that possible/recommended? due to the fact that it is still alpha version.

Comment: https://github.com/geoext/geoext2

Comment: yes this is the online link I use. Do you recommend me to download the src and have it locally though it is still alpha?

Comment: If you want to use geoext2 on your local machine, you'll need to clone the geoext2 repo from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the comment-answers above:

- There is not yet a formal release of geoext2 - it is pre-release software
- geoext2 is available at https://github.com/geoext/geoext2
- if you want to use it, then you should make sure you have a local copy (cloned from github) that you test your specific code against.
- if you choose to upgrade your local copy (at a later stage), make sure it works for your application.

Also, you should report problems and any fixes you find along the way, to make sure that the released version of geoext2 is as good as it can be for everyone (including you and I!).